# IBM Http Server - unable to update cookie

Tags: setcookie, ibmhttpserver

Good Day to you.
Our organization is using IBM HTTP Server 6 (Server version: IBM_HTTP_Server/6.1.0.47-PI31516 Apache/2.0.47)
We have a requirement to update an cookie parameter/attribute from web server. I have tried options from stackflow and other sites. However I cannot get the current value of the cookie

httpd.conf Entry

```
SetEnvIf Cookie "TEST_COOKIE=([^;]+)" AuthUniqueId=$1
Header add Set-Cookie "TEST_COOKIE=%{AuthUniqueId}e; SameSite=None; Secure; path=/" env=AuthUniqueId
```

I can see the cookie TEST_COOKIE set in response. however the value is always $1
Can you help in advising how to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SetEnvIf in IHS 6.1 (which is out of service for years) does not support substituting regex backreferences.